# Вероятность выборки между двумя элементами массива JS

Tags: javascript

Если примерно такой код :

```
var name=['Red','Green'];
var vr=50; // вероятность выбора между элементами массива
```

Если vr=50, нужно получить :

Red
Green
Red
Green

Если vr=25, нужно получить примерно такое :

Red
Green
Green
Green

Если vr=75, нужно получить, примерно такое :

Green
Green
Green
Red

---

Как правильно такое сделать?

Answer (score 0):

если случайно выбрать, то есть же простой метод

1. получаете число от `0` до `1`
2. если число больше `p`, то выбираете один элемент иначе другой

код:

```
const name=['Red','Green'];

const p_limit = 0.75

arr = Array()

for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const p = Math.random();

    arr.push(p > p_limit ? name[0] : name[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Функция выбирает псевдо-рандомный вариант из массива variants 
//                           c перевесами  в массиве possibility
const getRandomVariant = (variants, possibility) =>
  variants[possibility.map((v,k) => new Array(v).fill(k)).flat()
  [Math.trunc(Math.random()*possibility.reduce((s,p)=>s+p,0))]];

// Функция выбирает серию длиной count псевдо-рандомных вариантов, которые
// берутся из массива variants c перевесами в массиве possibility
const getSeries = (variants, possibility, count) => 
  new Array(count).fill('').map(() => 
    getRandomVariant(variants, possibility))
  .join(' ');

// Два варианта, перевес на вариант с индексом [0] = 4:1
console.log( getSeries(['a','b'],[4,1],100) );
// Два варианта, перевес на вариант с индексом [1] = 1:4
console.log( getSeries(['a','b'],[1,4],100) );

// Три варианта перевес соответствует соотношению 1:2:3
console.log( getSeries(['a','b','c'],[1,2,3],100) );
// Три варианта перевес соответствует соотношению 5:1:5
console.log( getSeries(['a','b','c'],[5,1,5],100) );
// Три варианта перевес соответствует соотношению 5:100:5
console.log( getSeries(['a','b','c'],[5,100,5],100) );
```